# Add where conditions on a Firebase query dynamically

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a query with several where conditions dynamically.

Context : An user select some filters like "brown hair", "tall" etc.. and I want to get in Firebase the corresponding data.

Currently, I have all my filter inside an object :

```
var whereConditions = {fieldName: "value", fieldname: "value"};
```

in our case :

```
var whereConditions = {"hairColor": "brown", "height": "tall"};
```

With this object, I would like to build the query :

```
var docRef = db.collection("people").where("hairColor","==","brown").where("height","==","tall")
```

But I'm facing an issue, I have no idea how many filters the user will choose (so, no idea about the number of where conditions), and I have no idea how to build this query.

I tried something like this, but it's not working :

```
for (var key in listCondition) {
   whereCond = whereCond + '.where(' + key + ', "==", ' + listCondition[key] + ')';
}

var docRef = db.collection("people").whereCond
```

I was pretty sure it wouldn't work, but I tried some stuff before coming here for help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `collection` and `where` return Query objects, and you can build on top of them as needed.

Comment: That's what I tried to do, but I don't know how to build the full query, while I'm in a loop

Comment: I just saw the duplicate post, I'm looking at it

Comment: You tried to build a string with a query.  You can't do that. You have to directly call the methods.

Comment: can you post your full solution here pease @Gio